# How close is it to reality in future of consciousness to be transferable as shown in the movie Chappie?

Tags: consciousness, philosophy-of-mind, artificial-intelligence, awareness

This question was inspired by the most creative thing ever to come up in a movie, namely the transfer of a consciousness from one body to another (may it be biological, or via non-biological methods).

I have always thought of consciousness as the result of a neural network communicating with the various parts of the brain, which in turn stores all of our experiences, thereby giving meaning to the sensations we perceive through our sensory organs that may aid in self-sustainability.

Comment: Welcome to Cognitive Sciences. I tried to make your question a bit more accessible. Feel free to roll back though.

Comment: "the most creative thing ever to come up in a movie" ...Hmmm. I'd respectfully ask you to consider reevaluating that statement after you see many more movies (of the right sort). Still, an interesting question for here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a network of neurons the only factor in memory?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/is-a-network-of-neurons-the-only-factor-in-memory)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen - and enjoyed! - the movie last week-end and asked myself the same question.

Let's face it, we are so far from being able to transfer knowledge from one human being to a machine with the help of a "mind-reader". The main point is that we don't have a useful brain signal to read from (the ones we know have structural limits).

No good brain signal, no associated technology and no reading device. On the contrary, we probably have the technology at the end of the human-to-machine process (a way to transfer and store a mind).